# Rounded corner in middle bootstrap button groups is missing when right button is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button group and sometime I need to hide the last right button based on user interaction. If I hide the right button the middle button will lose it's rounded corner design. I want the middle button to also have rounded corner when the right button is hidden. In the example below, `Middle` will lose it's rounded corner when user hide the right button.

html:

```
<br>
<div class="btn-group ml-3 mt-3" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Right</button>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success show ml-3 mt-3">
show
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hide ml-3 mt-3">
hide
</button>
```

javascript

```
$( ".show" ).click(function() {
  $( ".btn-danger" ).show();
});

$( ".hide" ).click(function() {
  $( ".btn-danger" ).hide();
});
```

The example with jsfiddle is using BS 4 while I use BS 3. It has the same problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/gotmvrsj/

Is there any bootstrap class for BS 3 that can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add/removeClass` to `warning` button

and set in css  `border-bottom-right-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` to this `class`

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f47bLk3t/)

```js
$( ".show" ).click(function() {
  $( ".btn-danger" ).show();
   $( ".btn-warning" ).removeClass('hideWarning');
});

$( ".hide" ).click(function() {
  $( ".btn-danger" ).hide();
  $( ".btn-warning" ).addClass('hideWarning');
 
});
```

```css
.hideWarning{
  border-bottom-right-radius:4px!important;
  border-top-right-radius:4px!important;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br>
<div class="btn-group ml-3 mt-3" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Right</button>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success show ml-3 mt-3">
show
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hide ml-3 mt-3">
hide
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach if you would like to use

```
<br>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Middle</button>
<button id="right-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Right</button>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success show">
show
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success hide">
hide
</button>




var store=$("#right-btn").clone();
var isActive=1;

$( ".show" ).click(function() {
if(isActive === 0){
$( ".btn-group" ).append(store);
isActive=1;
}
});


$( ".hide" ).click(function() {
if(isActive===1){
$( ".btn-danger" ).remove("#right-btn");
isActive=0;
}
});
```